# Positioning 1px off in Safari/Mac but works on Safari/Windows

Tags: css, macos, safari

I'm beating my head against a wall on this one; the logo image ("It's All About Revenue") shifts up by one pixel in Safari on Mac, but renders correctly in all other browser/OS combinations I've been able to test. Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be? Here's the site: http://blog.eloqua.com/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried to set the line-height of your H1 to 1em ? (windows and macos renders fonts and lineheights little differently)

Comment: I just tried changing the line-height to 1em but it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: Does it do the same in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it does look like it's also happening in Chrome on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `height` attribute of the `<div class="parentLogo">` element is being computed differently between the two browsers:

You need to set its `height` attribute manually:

```
.custom .parentLogo {
    height: 40px;
    ...
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: 6 years later and still helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this 1px bug many times, notably when using CSS resets. It is infact a line-height issue.

Set a base line-height for all browsers:

```
body {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```